# Opportunity and Account Relationships

Tags: trigger, opportunity, lookup, account, master-detail

We know that deleting the Account deletes the related opportunities(considering Master details relationships). However, if I delete an opportunity related to Account, will it cause the update of its parent Account Object?
For example consider following code:

```
trigger accountTrigger on Account (before update){
Boolean processOpportunity = false;
List<opportunity> opptysClosedLost = new List<opportunity>()
List<opportunity> lstAllOpp = [select StageName
from Opportunity where accountId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
if(!lstAllOpp.isEmpty())
processOpportunity = true;
while(processOpportunity){
for(opportunity o : lstAllOpp)
if(o.StageName == 'Closed - Lost')
opptysClosedLost.add(o);
processOpportunity = false;
if(!opptysClosedLost.isEmpty())
**delete opptysClosedLost;**
```

This line will cause the error as:

```
System.DmlException: Delete failed.First exception onrow 0 with id
    00690000008o3cB AAQ; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER,
    Object (id = 0019000000GvLaC ) is currently in trigger accountTrigger,
    therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []:Trigger.accountTrigger:
```

Answer (score 2):

## "Maybe"

If you have a rollup summary field, or a process builder, this can cause the recursion you're seeing. However, this is only because you've chosen to use a before update trigger event. The proper solution would be to use an after update trigger event.

## Optimization

You could write this all in 3 lines of code, ignoring error handling:

```
trigger accountTrigger on Account (after update) {
  delete [select id from opportunity where accountid = :trigger.new and stagename = 'closed - lost'];
}
```

The main points here are: (a) prefer filtering over if statements when possible, and (b) you don't need to check if a list is empty first, either to iterate over or to perform a DML on.